# How does a browser retrieve Scorm API from Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, scorm

I have some content developed by Articulate for an LMS. It's failing on searching for which API my LMS is using.

I see code such as the following:
https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/api-discovery-algorithms/

How does my server / lms share what API im using for scorm?

I'm trying to reverse engineer the LMS code as I'm a new admin over that system.

Curious if there's is a standard that I could query the code for -

Let me know what I can expand on -

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SCORM runtime is a JavaScript interface that is effectively "namespaced" as a global variable in the window context of some window in the hierarchy at or above the content. For SCORM 2004 it is the global variable `API_1484_11` (hence the `win.API_1484_11` in the linked code). For SCORM 1.2 it is just `API` (hence `win.API`). Therefore your LMS must have in one of the parent windows of the launched SCO, JavaScript that has a global variable called either `API` or `API_1484_11` that implements the SCORM runtime API. Naturally `API_1484_11` is fairly searchable as it is pretty specific, `API` less so, but the key will be that it will be in some JavaScript (if the LMS implements one of the SCORM versions). You may also want to try in a browser's developer tools to locate the global variable in the various windows in the hierarchy as their tools usually autocomplete available variables, etc. You then might be able to reference back more easily. Note that for the purposes of SCORM a frame is considered a "window".